# wrapping a link with a div element & disable the divs line break

Tags: jquery, css

I wrapped a link with a div-element

```
$("a[href$='name']").wrap("<div />");
```

The div-element causes line breaks. To prevent this behaviour I'd like to style my div-element with style="white-space: nowrap;".

I tried

```
$("a[href$='name']").wrap("<div style='white-space: nowrap;'></div>");
```

For some reason it doesn't work. There is no error shown. The line break however is still active.

What's wrong with my snippet?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This clearly points out the difference between div and span - div is a block level element, span is an inline element.  (css can work around this).  Other than that, they are both used to imply logical grouping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you wrap an element inside a `div` it will surely break in line since the `div` element will consume the whole line. Why not wrap it with `span` instead if you want to maintain the continuity of the paragraph or sentence or phrase?

Comment: Thta' it. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

If for any reason the element NEEDS to be a div, and cannot be a span. You could give the div:

```
display: inline-block;
```

to get similar behaviour.

Comment: in IE7, it will still break the line.